# How can I fill a vector with iterators of a different type?

Tags: c++, boost, vector, iterator

I have many examples of the following code:

```
struct foo1
{
    foo1(int ii = 0, int jj = 0)
    {
        this->ii = ii;
        this->jj = jj;
    }

    int ii;
    int jj;
};

struct foo2
{
    foo2()
    {
    }

    foo2(const foo1& f)
    {
        this->f = f;
    }

    foo1 f;
};
typedef std::vector< foo2 > foo_v;

typedef std::set< int > bar_s;

bar_s barSet;
barSet.insert(1); barSet.insert(2); barSet.insert(3);
barSet.insert(4); barSet.insert(5); barSet.insert(6);

...

foo_v fooVec;
for (bar_s::iterator b = barSet.begin(); b != barSet.end(); ++b)
    fooVec.push_back(foo2(*b));
```

**How can I improve the code where it's filling a new vector of foo2?**

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
std::remove_copy_if(barSet.begin(), barSet.end(), 
                    std::back_inserter(fooVec), ...)
```

but I'm struggling to find a way to bind the `int` type to new instances of the `foo2` struct.

---

Note:

```
std::copy(barSet.begin(), barSet.end(), std::back_inserter(fooVec));
```

gives me the following error:

*Error  1   error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)*

Comment: If you dereference an iterator on `bar_s`, that would result in an `int`. Now, `int` can already be converted to `foo`, so you should be able to insert the value behind an iterator on `bar_s` into `foo_v`

Answer (score 3):

```
std::copy(barSet.begin(), barSet.end(), std::back_inserter(fooVec));
```

int is convertable to `foo' (the only constructor can be called with one int argument and it is not explicit).

> Error 1 error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

This is because foo2 can not be contstructed from int, only from foo1 and only one step of implicit conversion is allowed. You can you std::transform:

```
std::transform(barSet.begin(), barSet.end(), 
               std::back_inserter(fooVec), 
               boost::lambda::constructor<foo2>());
```

The boost::lambda::constructor() can be replaced with std::fun_ptr(makeFoo2):

```
foo2 makeFoo2(const foo& f) { return f; }
```

Comment: Sorry, I've modified my code above - I have in my real code multiple constructors.

Comment: No problem. foo still has a constructor that can be called with one int argument. You can add yet another constructor, e.g. from double or string or whatever you what, and you still be able to implicitly construct foo from int (and additionally from double, string, etc).

Comment: STL containers also have constructor from two iterators, this will copy the specified range of another container.

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far... apologies, but my example was wrong (again).  I modified it and I've also given the compile error I get when using std::copy

Answer (score 0):

You can use the vector's constructor that takes a pair of iterators.

```
foo_v fooVec(barSet.begin(), barSet.end());
```

Given the constructors of `foo`, `int` is implicitly convertible to `foo`.